# How to refresh the page and set a counterto tableview

Tags: javascript

I have a HTMLB Tableview. Every 3mins I need to set its `firstRowVisible` property to a dynamic value i.e. if its zero the first time then after 3mins it should set to 21 and so on.

Can you please tell me a possible solution to set this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback and `setTimeout`

For example:

```
var callback = function(){
   //do something with firstRowVisible
};
setTimeout(callback, 3 * 60 * 1000); //after 3 minutes
```